# Highlight keyword using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So I am writing a python script that identifies keywords in certain columns in excel. I want to add functionality to highlight/change the color of keywords when I find them.

```
for i in self.data:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(i)
    sheet = wb.active
    store_keyword = self.whichColumnEntry.get()
    keyword_column = self.whichSearchColumnEntry.get()
    keyword = self.keywordEntry.get()
    sheet[store_keyword + '1'] = 'Keyword'
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        test = sheet[keyword_column + str(row)].value
        if test.find(keyword) >= 0:
            sheet[store_keyword + str(row)] = keyword
            times_found += 1
    wb.save(i)
```

That is the code I'm using so far. If it finds the keyword in a cell it adds the keyword to a new column at the end of the spreadsheet. Is there a way I can highlight the keyword as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight how?
Changing the cell colour?

openpyxl docs: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html

e.g. the following should produce a yellow cell with the keyword in it:

```
from openpyxl.styles import colors

#... some code...

    mycell = sheet[store_keyword + str(row)]
    mycell.value = keyword
    mycell.fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor=colors.YELLOW)
```

Comment: I want to highlight the actual word. Or change the color of the word. There are paragraphs in each cell so highlighting the entire cell doesn't really work.

Thanks for replying!

Comment: Excel does now support formatting beneath the cell level.  However I believe this is fairly recent.  I do not believe that openpyxl supports this.

Comment: Balls. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I'm using your highlight solution btw so thanks again!